# C# to VB.NET - Public unsafe struct to public structure

Tags: c#, vb.net

could anyone help me translate the following C# code snippet to VB.NET?

```
public unsafe struct T14443aRequest
{
public fixed byte CardID[10];
public byte CardIDLength;
public byte CardClassSAK;
public fixed byte CardClassATQA[2];
public byte CardClassType; // NXP Mifare 1K=0x10, NXP Mifare Ultralight=0x40
};
T14443aRequest Request = new T14443aRequest();
res = Iso14443a106Request(ref Request);
```

Comment: Why perform such a conversion at all? Why not *use* the C# library?

Comment: I have a DLL written in C++ that integrates with custom RFID hardware. The RFID component's documentation only shows how to use functions with C# or C++, as I am developing an application in VB.NET it would be amazing to solve the integration with the C++ DLL without C# or C++. 

Some functions like connecting to the RFID module already works fine by calling the C++ DLL from VB.NET.

Comment: You can have mixed C# and VB.Net Projects in a Solution that can integrate seamlessly.  As you probably know, the development of the VB.Net language has come to a stop. This kind of *solution* may become more and more necessary in the future. You should probably get the hang of it.

Comment: The development of VB.NET hasn't come to a stop. Microsoft keeps supporting it and adding new features BUT *developers* have abandoned it for over a decade. All OSS projects, all NuGet packages, are developed in C# and/or F#. VB.NET offers no benefits over C# or F# in any kind of development

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos [Visual Basic support planned for .NET 5.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/vbteam/visual-basic-support-planned-for-net-5-0/). Third paragraph. This has been repeatedly stated over the last 3 years. I wasn't referring to the porting VB.Net to .Net 5 (still incomplete, so standard VB.Net features cannot still be used in .Net 5). It's related to the core language itself. Sure, some changes are necessary to adapt to .Net 5 and will be performed over time. This doesn't change the language development plan (which focuses on *stability*).

Comment: As @Jimi says, simply add a C# project to your solution to contain anything you can't - or can't easily - do in VB and reference it from wherever you like. I've done it before and it's the cleanest, most maintainable solution in these cases. Doing this is only going to become more "normal" as time goes by and VB.NET retreats into the distance ala Latin.

Answer (score 1):

VB.Net doesn't provide unsafe code and pointers (which is what those `fixed` arrays are). Use C#.

Comment: Is there any alternative way to avoid using fixed arrays? 

Huge part of my application is already built with VB.NET, it would be amazing to find a way to solve this without C#.

Comment: Depending on how you use the array, you could explicitly provide the array items as individual fields (like `public byte CardID0; public byte CardID1;` etc).